# Ruby Class method or Constant, best practice

Tags: ruby, class-constants

One of my ruby classes draws data from a rather large, local, XML file that will only change with a new deploy.

Is the best practice in this case to keep the document as a constant, like:

```
class Product 
  XML_DOC = Nokogiri::XML(open("#{Rails.root}/myxmlfile.xml"))
end
```

or to access the document through a class method, like:

```
class Product 
 self.xml_doc
    Nokogiri::XML(open("#{Rails.root}/myxmlfile.xml"))
  end
end
```

I think that the class method may be the way to go, since it will be easier to mock in tests, but what's considered the best-practice for keeping an in-memory file like this?

Comment: I like gioele's answer to your specific question, but I don't like your question. :-)

Rather instantiate a product object as part of program setup. "I only need one" is not a good reason to throw object orientation out the window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the most common idiom:

```
class Product 
    def xml_doc
       @@xml_doc ||= Nokogiri::XML(open("#{Rails.root}/myxmlfile.xml"))
       return @@xml_doc
    end
end
```

The `||=` operator says "if the variable is `nil`, calculate the result of the expresion and store it, otherwise do nothing". This idiom is called "memoization".

Do no think of constants as a way to optimize your code, in Ruby they are not really constant anyway.

Comment: you can remove the second line with the return, is not needed.

Comment: Depending on your implementation of Ruby, an implicit return may actually be faster.